# How to break for loop after got two matching from json response

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I just wondering is it possible to break the loop for after getting 1 or 2 results and asign it variables with same condition.

```
import json

lookup_dt = "2022-03-09"

r = '{"DBClusterSnapshots": [{"DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier": "snap-1", "DBClusterIdentifier": "aurora-cluster", "SnapshotCreateTime": "2022-03-09", "Engine": "aurora-postgresql", "EngineVersion": "12.7", "SnapshotType": "manual"}, {"DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier": "snap-2", "DBClusterIdentifier": "aurora-cluster", "SnapshotCreateTime": "2022-03-09", "Engine": "aurora-postgresql", "EngineVersion": "12.7", "SnapshotType": "manual"}, {"DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier": "snap-3", "DBClusterIdentifier": "aurora-cluster", "SnapshotCreateTime": "2022-03-09", "Engine": "aurora-postgresql", "EngineVersion": "12.7", "SnapshotType": "manual"}]}'

data = json.loads(r)


snap = [
    d["DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier"]
    for d in response["DBClusterSnapshots"]
    if d['SnapshotCreateTime'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == lookup_dt
]

SnapshotId, SnapshotId2,..n = SnapshotId_l[:n]

if SnapshotId :
    print("INFO: Found manual snapshots for requested date: " + str(SnapshotId))
elif: SnapshotId2
    print("INFO: Found manual snapshots for requested date: " + str(SnapshotId2))
else:
    print("ERROR: Snapshot did not find for requested date : " + str(args_lookup_dt))
    exit(1)
```

Let say with `if d['SnapshotCreateTime'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == lookup_dt` condition we could get sometimes 1 or more. date might be same but there will some fractional time difference. my use case is get mactching one and assign `varaible`, if two assign it two `varivales` and if more than two just stick with onyl two.

I would expecting output like if of the vairable true print it.

Is this possible or doesn't make any senesce of it?

Comment: use a `for` loop iterating over 2 times at most

Comment: Why are you using a loop? The `while` condition never changes.

Comment: `["SnapshotCreateTime"]`  won’t be alway same from `json` response

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension to put all the snapshot names into a list:

```
import json

lookup_dt = "2022-03-09"
r = '{"DBClusterSnapshots": [{"DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier": "snap-1", "DBClusterIdentifier": "aurora-cluster", "SnapshotCreateTime": "2022-03-09", "Engine": "aurora-postgresql", "EngineVersion": "12.7", "SnapshotType": "manual"}, {"DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier": "snap-2", "DBClusterIdentifier": "aurora-cluster", "SnapshotCreateTime": "2022-03-09", "Engine": "aurora-postgresql", "EngineVersion": "12.7", "SnapshotType": "manual"}, {"DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier": "snap-3", "DBClusterIdentifier": "aurora-cluster", "SnapshotCreateTime": "2022-03-09", "Engine": "aurora-postgresql", "EngineVersion": "12.7", "SnapshotType": "manual"}]}'
data = json.loads(r)

snaps = [
    d["DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier"]
    for d in data["DBClusterSnapshots"]
    if d["SnapshotCreateTime"] == lookup_dt
]
print(snaps)  # ['snap-1', 'snap-2', 'snap-3']
```

If you want to assign the first two of those to the variables `snap1` and `snap2` you could do:

```
snap1, snap2 = snaps[:2]
```

but in practice you'll probably find it easier to just use that `snaps` list as-is.

(edit) Per comments, if you want a dict of snapshot ID to creation time, that would be:

```
snap_times = {
    d["DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier"]: d["SnapshotCreateTime"]
    for d in data["DBClusterSnapshots"]
    if d["SnapshotCreateTime"] == lookup_dt
}

print(snap_times)
# {'snap-1': '2022-03-09', 'snap-2': '2022-03-09', 'snap-3': '2022-03-09'}
```

Note that since we filtered using `lookup_dt`, all the creation times will equal `lookup_dt`.  If you don't want that, just remove the `if d["SnapshotCreateTime"] == lookup_dt` line.

Comment: I have tried this method, in real time `['SnapshotCreateTime']` could more than 3. So I want only two matching all json part  like its closet to given `lookup_dt`.

Comment: Does taking the `snaps[:2]` slice like I showed in my answer not work?  If not you might need to give a better example of what you're trying to get, since `snaps[:2]` is `snaps-1` and `snaps-2` exactly like you asked for in the original question.

Comment: Sorry for unclear. Pretty similar, but I wanted with additional data as well. 
```
'snap-1': SnapshotCreateTime,
 'snap-2':SnapshotCreateTime,
 'snap-3': SnapshotCreateTime
```

Comment: Oh -- why didn't you include that in your question?  That's a pretty simple change, updating my answer.

Comment: Wondering how to slice dict to mulriple. tryied `snap1, snap2 = snaps_times[:2]` but got this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Comment: try `list(snaps_times.items())[:2]`.  If you don't want a dict, though, you could just use a list comprehension (making a list of tuples) instead of a dict comprehension.  It's hard to figure out what exactly you're trying to achieve when the requirements keep changing.

Comment: Sorry for confusion . Let say with `if d['SnapshotCreateTime'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == lookup_dt` condition we could get sometimes 1 or more than one. date might be same but there will some fractional time difference. my use case is get mactching one and assign `varaible`, if two assign it two `varivales` and if more than two just stick with onyl two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245312/discussion-between-rj-n-and-samwise).